# Rules to determine "unforced errors" and "winners" in tennis?

Tags: rules, tennis, atp, wta

Is there any rule to understand when a shot is an "unforced error" or a "winner" in a objective meaning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a clear cut definition for a **Winner** statistic. If Player A hits the ball & Player B is unable to touch it with his racquet before the ball bounces twice,
then it's a **Winner** for Player A. A **Service Winner** is another name for **Ace**. So this statistic is very objective.

However, when it comes to **Unforced Error**, the decision is purely subjective. It depends of the situation. If Player A
hits the ball in the middle of the court & Player B has ample time to play the shot but sends it out or into the net, then it's an **Unforced Error**. However, if Player B is on the run while playing the shot & sends it out or into the net then it would not count as an **Unforced Error** but rather **Forced Error**.
So this statistic is purely subjective.

Ofcourse, no official rules. They are mere statistics.

Comment: A service winner is not the same thing as an ace. Ace is an untouched serve by the returner's racquet. A service winner can be touched.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that, roughly : An **unforced error** is when a player shoots the ball and sends it out of the field or in the net, and if this error comes "only" from *poor judgement* or *execution* from the player . A **winner** is when a player shoots the ball so that he wins the point on this shoot (the opponent *does not reach the ball*).

I don't think there is a written rule for it, as this may be only used for statistical purposes.

EDIT : Maybe this question will be closed as this seems to be a duplicate of this one : [When does a point count as a winner and when as unforced error?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/2626/when-does-a-point-count-as-a-winner-and-when-as-unforced-error?rq=1)

Comment: In my opinion it is not so easy: when a player play a smash and the opponent touch the ball with the racket sending it in the tribune. Reading your reply it seems an "unforced", isn't it?

Comment: Nope. This error is a froced one, caused by the player's good play. The unforced error occurs when it comes from a poor judgement or execution. But judging whether an error is forced or unforced is quite subjective.